# Randomize Numbers from a specific list

Tags: vb.net

I want my application to populate random sets of numbers using a list of specific numbers that i chose.  For example; I have a set of numbers (1,3,5,9,21,70,56).  I want to be able to randomize the order in which these numbers are selected.  Is that possible? We are playing a prank on my boss while we are working from home.  He wins every game/raffle here we have at work.  Since we have been working from home, i created a bingo game... Each person has to choose a line  (1-15) and the numbers with the corresponding line is your bingo card....so we want to pull a prank on him... for the line he chooses, we dont want any number to generate on that line.  for example: if he chooses line 1,the numbers on that line are 1,16, 31, 46 and 61, I dont want any of those numbers to be choosen.  I have a randomizer to choose random numbers ( so he can at least when once).  But we dont want him to win. So I want the btnGetMoney to call the GetMoneyRand procedure to only choose numbers from an array of numbers I list.  Is this possible?

```
Public Class Form1
Private numberList As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Button)
Private randomLog As New List(Of Integer)


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    radVertical.Checked = True
    FlowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = True

    numMin.Value = 1
    numMax.Value = 75
    numMin.Minimum = 1
End Sub

Private Sub radVertical_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radVertical.CheckedChanged
    FlowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = If(radVertical.Checked, FlowDirection.TopDown, FlowDirection.LeftToRight)
End Sub

Private Sub StartGame()
    btnRandom.Enabled = True
    btnStart.Enabled = False
    btnStop.Enabled = True
    GroupBox1.Enabled = False
    GroupBox2.Enabled = False
    btnGetMoney.Enabled = True
    Dim numRange As List(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(numMin.Value, numMax.Value).ToList()

    For Each number In numRange
        Dim btn As New Button()
        btn.Name = "btn" & number
        btn.Size = New Size(40, 40)
        btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
        btn.Text = number
        btn.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14)

        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn)

        numberList.Add(number, btn)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub StopGame()
    btnRandom.Enabled = False
    btnStart.Enabled = True
    btnStop.Enabled = False
    GroupBox1.Enabled = True
    GroupBox2.Enabled = True

    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear()
    numberList.Clear()
    randomLog.Clear()

    lblRandomNumber.Text = "000"
End Sub

Private Sub DoRandomNumer()
    If randomLog.Count = numberList.Count Then
        MsgBox("No more number for random")
        Return
    End If

    ' animation random
    For i As Integer = 1 To 100
        Dim rndDummy As Integer = CInt(numMax.Value * Rnd())
        lblRandomNumber.Text = rndDummy
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
        Application.DoEvents()
    Next

    Randomize()

    Dim rndNumber As Integer = (numMax.Value * Rnd())
    While randomLog.Contains(rndNumber) Or rndNumber = 0
        rndNumber = (numMax.Value * Rnd())
    End While

    randomLog.Add(rndNumber)
    lblRandomNumber.Text = rndNumber
    numberList(rndNumber).BackColor = Color.LightBlue
End Sub
Private Sub GetMoneyRand()


End Sub
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    StartGame()
End Sub

Private Sub btnStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
    StopGame()
End Sub

Private Sub btnRandom_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRandom.Click
    DoRandomNumer()
End Sub

Private Sub btnGetMoney_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetMoney.Click
    GetMoneyRand()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: If you are going to use `Randomize` and `Rnd` then at least do it properly, i.e. call `Randomize` once and once only`. That said, don't. Use the .NET `Random` class. Again, create a single instance and reuse it rather than creating an instance each time you need a random number. Using different instances within different types/objects in your project is one thing but just use one instance within each type/object.

Comment: Choosing random numbers from a provided list is easy: your random pull is the index into the list (so from a list with 5 items, you would get a random number between 0 and 4).  Make sure you use the correct routine for this; naively implemented, it's easy to bias the selection toward the front of the range (and there can be more subtle biases that depend on the quality of individual bits within the return from the random routine).

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Dim rng As New Random
Dim myRandomList = myList.OrderBy(Function(item) rng.NextDouble()).ToArray()
```

That will create an array containing the items from the original list in random order. It doesn't matter the type of the list (any `IEnumerable(Of T)` will do) or the type of the items. You can call `ToList` instead of `ToArray` if you want a `List(Of T)` instead of an array or you can drop the `ToArray` and passed the ordered list to the constructor for a queue if you want to pick off the items one by one, e.g.

```vb
Dim rng As New Random
Dim myRandomQueue As New Queue(Of Integer)(myList.OrderBy(Function(item) rng.NextDouble()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do

if number = 1 then
generate new number
elseif number = 16 then
generate new number
elseif number = 31 then
generate new number
elseif number = 46 then
generate new number
elseif number = 61 then
generate new number
else

exit do 'exits the loop if number is different then above :)

loop
```